# Why am I getting a warning about cudaMemcpyToArray(...) being deprecated?

Tags: cuda, compiler-warnings

What is this warning and how can I fix it?

```
warning: ‘cudaError_t cudaMemcpyToArray(cudaArray_t, size_t, size_t, const void*, size_t, cudaMemcpyKind)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
```

Comment: Deprecated means exactly that. This function is slated for removal from the API at some point in the future and you should use an alternative array API like `cudaMemcpy2DToArray ` instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deprecated means it is not recommended for use, and *the support for it may be dropped in the very next CUDA release*.

A description of what to do about it is given [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cudamemcpytoarray-is-deprecated/71385/10).

For a typical usage where you are copying an entire allocation from host to device, and the source (host) allocation is a flat (unpitched) allocation of width `w` elements by height `h` rows, perhaps something like this:

```
cudaMemcpyToArray(dst, 0, 0, src, h*w*sizeof(src[0]), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)
```

You would replace it with:

```
cudaMemcpy2DToArray(dst, 0, 0, src, w*sizeof(src[0]) , w*sizeof(src[0]), h, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

The replacement API (`cudaMemcpy2DToArray`) is documented [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g9509226164aaa58baf0c5b8ed165df58).

Note that in the example that I have given, if you have no sense of a "2D" allocation consisting of rows and columns, but instead have a single flat allocation of (let's say) `w` elements, you can simply set `h=1` in the formulation above.

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks Robert