# What's "pitch" in cudaMemcpy2DToArray and cudaMemcpy2DFromArray

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm converting the deprecated `cudaMemcpyToArray` and `cudaMemcpyFromArray` into  `cudaMemcpy2DToArray` and `cudaMemcpy2DFromArray`. Rather than `size` of the deprecated calls, the new API calls for `width`, `height`, and `pitch`. The descriptions of `spitch` and `dpitch` are correspondingly "Pitch of source memory" and "Pitch of destination memory". I wonder what are those values: size of data items, something else?

More specifically, if I were to copy `W*H` floats, should I have `pitch=sizeof(float)`, `width=W`, `height=H`, or `pitch=sizeof(float)*W`, `width=sizeof(float)*W`, `height=H`, or something else?

Comment: The documentation tells you: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g9509226164aaa58baf0c5b8ed165df58 "spitch is the width in memory in bytes of the 2D array pointed to by src, including any padding added to the end of each row."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
pitch=sizeof(float)*W
width = sizeof(float)*W
height = H
```

The above is for `cudaMemcpy2DToArray`, and assumes you are transferring from host to device, which would most likely involve an unpitched allocation in host memory as the source.

The pitch of a *pitched allocation* is the size in bytes of one line of of a 2D allocation, including padding bytes at the end of the line.  It is the value returned by `cudaMallocPitch`, for example.  For unpitched allocations, it is still the width of the line, and it is given by `W*sizeof(element)` where the 2D allocation width is given by `W` elements each of size `sizeof(element)`.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67772887/warning-cudaerror-t-cudamemcpytoarraycudaarray-t-size-t-size-t-const-void/67776418#67776418) and [the link it refers to](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cudamemcpytoarray-is-deprecated/71385/10) may also be of interest.

Comment: The top answer to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67772887/warning-cudaerror-t-cudamemcpytoarraycudaarray-t-size-t-size-t-const-void/67776418#67776418) you mentioned seems to recommend that both `pitch` and `width` should be `sizeof(float)*W`

Comment: The difference will be whether you are referring to source or destination pitch, and whether the underlying allocation is pitched or unpitched.  There is not enough information in your question to tell what scenario exactly you are asking about.  Nevertheless, I have covered both cases (pitched and unpitched allocations) in my answer.

Comment: for [cudaMemcpy2DToArray](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g9509226164aaa58baf0c5b8ed165df58) specifically, only the source pitch is relevant (only pitch argument is `spitch`).  So the actual pitch value you pass for that will first of all depend on whether your source allocation (which you created, and have not shown) is pitched or unpitched.    If you are copying from host memory to the cudaArray, it is probably unpitched, and so you would use `W*sizeof(element)` for the pitch value.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were asking about pitch.  Yes, my answer was incorrect, and I fixed it just now.  The width of the transfer is columns in bytes, not elements.

Comment: Thanks, changed the calls accordingly.